# Access to first key of a nested json using jq and obtain its value

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "query": "rest ec",
    "elected_facts_mapping": {
        "AWS": {
            "ECS": {
                "attachments": [
                    "restart_ecs"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Great!"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "top_facts_mapping": {
        "AWS": {
            "ECS": {
                "attachments": [
                    "restart_ecs"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Great!"
                ]
            },
            "EC2": {
                "attachments": [
                    "create_ec2"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Awesome"
                ]
            }
        },
        "GitHub": {
            "Pull": {
                "attachments": [
                    "pull_req"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Be right on it"
                ]
            }
        },
        "testtttt": {
            "test": {
                "attachments": [
                    "hello_world"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Be right on it"
                ]
            }
        },
        "fgjgh": {
            "fnfgj": {
                "attachments": [
                    "hello_world"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Be right on it"
                ]
            }
        },
        "tessttertre": {
            "gfdgfdgfd": {
                "attachments": [
                    "hello_world"
                ],
                "text": [
                    "Great!"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "elected_facts_with_prefix_text": null
}
```

And I want to access to `top_facts_mapping's` first key `AWS` and it's first key `ECS`

I am trying to do this (in my DSL):

```
'.span | fromjson'
'.span_data.top_facts_mapping | keys[0]'
'.span_data.top_facts_mapping[${top_facts_prepare_top_fact_topic}] | keys[0]'
'.top_facts_prepare_top_fact_topic_subtopic[${top_facts_prepare_top_fact_topic}][${top_facts_prepare_top_fact_topic_subtopic}]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` to turn the object into an array of key-value pairs, then select the first value using `[0].value`

```bash
.top_facts_mapping | to_entries[0].value | to_entries[0].value
```

```json
{
  "attachments": [
    "restart_ecs"
  ],
  "text": [
    "Great!"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JsEVJityeDq)

If at one level the object may be empty, you can prepend each `to_entries` with `try` (optionally followed by a `catch` clause)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `keys_unsorted` builtin, since the underlying object is a dictionary and *not* a list

```
.top_facts_mapping | keys_unsorted[0] as $k | .[$k] | .[keys_unsorted[0]]
```

The above filter could be re-written with a simple function

```
def get_firstkey_val: keys_unsorted[0] as $k | .[$k];

.top_facts_mapping | 
  get_firstkey_val | get_firstkey_val
```

Or with some jq trick-play, assumes the path provided `top_facts_mapping` is guaranteed to exist

```
getpath([ paths | select(.[-3] == "top_facts_mapping" ) ] | first)
```

Since the `paths` built-in constructs the root to leaf paths as arrays, we all paths containing the second to last field (denoted by `.[-3]`) as `"top_facts_mapping"` which returns paths inside it

From which `first` selects the first entity in the list i.e. below list

```json
[
  "top_facts_mapping",
  "AWS",
  "ECS"
]
```

Use `getpath/1` to obtain the JSON value at the obtained path.

If there is a risk of the key `top_facts_mapping` not being present in the JSON, `getpath/1` could return an error as written above. Fix it by adding a proper check

```
([ paths | select(.[-3] == "top_facts_mapping" ) ] | first) as $p | 
if $p | length > 0 then getpath($p) else empty end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stream-based approach which disassembles the input using the `--stream` option, filters for the "top_facts_mapping" key on top level `.[0][0]`, truncates the stream to descend 3 levels, re-assembles the stream using `fromstream`, and outputs the `first` match:

```bash
jq --stream -n 'first(fromstream(3| truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "top_facts_mapping"))))'
```

```json
{
  "attachments": [
    "restart_ecs"
  ],
  "text": [
    "Great!"
  ]
}
```